# too many buckets exception in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I was trying to hit the query in elasticsearch 8.6.1
Getting this issue-

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "",
        "phase": "fetch",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [],
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "too_many_buckets_exception",
            "reason": "Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [65536] but this number of buckets was exceeded. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting.",
            "max_buckets": 65536
        }
    },
    "status": 503
}
```

Please suggest the solution. Thanks in advance

Checked how to change the bucket size.

Answer (score 0):

PUT _cluster/settings

```
{
    "persistent":{
        "search.max_buckets":20000
    }
}
```

Do note that search.max_buckets is a safety soft-limit designed to prevent bad aggregations from hurting nodes. Too many buckets consume much more memory, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the search.max_buckets and see what happens :
PUT _cluster/settings
{
"persistent":{
"search.max_buckets":50000
}
}
but this consume more memory and put a load on cluster or you can use downsampling feature in elasticsearch see this documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/downsampling.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Aside from linking to the Elasticsearch docs, does your answer add anything to what was already mentioned in [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286231/1519716)?